Make a Windows sandbox client full screen with Win32 api
I am trying to stitch Windows sandbox into our application panel. I am able to get handle for sandbox and set the position. But the sandbox does not fit in the panel, it has scrollbars, as shown in this screenshot:

I have tried using both SetWindowPos and MoveWindow along with ShowWindow, but nothing helps.
Any suggestion how to get the sandbox to fit in the panel?
This is what I have tried:
IntPtr childProcessHandle = new IntPtr(GetHandle(childProcessWindowName));

ShowWindowAsync(childProcessHandle, 5);

Win32Api.SetParent(childProcessHandle, new IntPtr(Int32.Parse(parentProcessHandle)));

long style = WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_VISIBLE;
style = style & ~WS_CAPTION & ~WS_THICKFRAME;

Win32Api.SetWindowLong(childProcessHandle, GWL_STYLE, style);
Win32Api.SetWindowPos(childProcessHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, width, height, Win32Api.SWP_FRAMECHANGED);


Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?: "It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws... near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree" (My emphasis)

Not exactly an answer to your question, but when running Windows 11 24H2, there's a (undocumented) way to host the Sandbox https://github.com/smourier/WinformsSandbox
